# ember.js - Get file that was uploaded in controller

Tags: forms, file-upload, file-io, ember.js

I have a file input in my view:

```
        <form {{action "file_upload" on="submit"}}>
            <p>{{input type="file" value=file}}</p>
            <p>{{input type="submit" value="Save"}}</p>
        </form>
```

My question is how do I get this file in the controller when the form submits?

Right now, I have:

```
    actions: {
      file_upload: function(){
        console.log(this.get('file'));
      }
    }
```

Just very simply trying to spit out to the console the file object, but this does not work. Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Maybe this workshop (https://github.com/bazzel/ember-workshop/wiki/04.0.0-Upload-Images) can help you? This includes the upload of images using Ember.

Comment: this returns the image in base64 format, is there a way to just post the file?